# Pandas -- .add() resulting in TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, addition

I've run into a bit of a problem adding Pandas dataframes using the .add() method. I have a data generator I'm using to generate synthetic data along a normal distribtuion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def DataSynthNormal(data, sel, column, fracFull, TotalRows, SelRows, mean, std, abst=False):
    fraction = data.loc[data['A'] == sel, column].sample(frac = fracFull).index
    if abst:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.absolute(np.random.normal(mean, std, round(SelRows*fracFull)).astype('int64')), index=fraction).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mean, std, round(SelRows*fracFull)).astype('int64'), index=fraction).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    data[column] = data[column].add(data1, fill_value=0)
```

Using a this dataframe as an example:

```
empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B'], index=range(0,10))
empty.A[0:4] = "C"; empty.A[4:7] = "D"; empty.A[7:10] = "E"
print(empty)
   A    B
0  C  NaN
1  C  NaN
2  C  NaN
3  C  NaN
4  D  NaN
5  D  NaN
6  D  NaN
7  E  NaN
8  E  NaN
9  E  NaN
```

And running the data generator:

```
DataSynthNormal(empty, 'C', 'B', 0.8, 10, 4, 0, 1)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       DataSynthNormal2(empty, 'C', 'B', 0.8, 10, 4, 0, 1)
>
> File "", line 7, in DataSynthNormal2
>       data[column] = data[column].add(data1, fill_value=0)
>
> File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 1358, in flex_wrapper
>       self.index).**finalize**(self)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 274, in **init**
>       raise_cast_failure=True)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 4163, in _sanitize_array
>       subarr = com._asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py",
>   line 317, in _asarray_tuplesafe
>       values = [tuple(x) for x in values]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py",
>   line 317, in 
>       values = [tuple(x) for x in values]
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I'm trying to use .add() here because it conserves NaN when two dataframes are added, as opposed to .fillna(0) (which has been outputting n x n matrices, for some reason). I want it to do this because the real data this is trying to emulate has both blanks and 0's throughout. I also can't use "data[column] = data1", because I need to use other conditionals (=='D', =='E') at different times and with different mean and std.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution, which involved creating a second function:

```
def DataSynthNormal(data, sel, column, fracFull, TotalRows, selRows, mean, std, abst=False):
    fraction = data.loc[data['A'] == sel, column].sample(frac = fracFull).index
    if abst:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.absolute(np.random.normal(mean, std, round(selRows*fracFull)).astype('int64')), index=fraction).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mean, std, round(selRows*fracFull)).astype('int64'), index=fraction).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    data[column] = data1
```

Here's the first one, works as you'd expect.

```
def DataSynthNormal2x(data, sel1, sel2, column, fracFull1, fracFull2, TotalRows, selRows1, selRows2, mean1, std1, mean2, std2, abst=False):
    fraction1 = data.loc[data['A'] == sel1, column].sample(frac = fracFull1).index
    fraction2 = data.loc[data['A'] == sel2, column].sample(frac = fracFull2).index
    if abst:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.absolute(np.random.normal(mean1, std1, round(selRows1*fracFull1)).astype('int64')), index=fraction1).reindex(range(TotalRows))
        data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.absolute(np.random.normal(mean2, std2, round(selRows2*fracFull2)).astype('int64')), index=fraction2).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    else:
        data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mean1, std1, round(selRows1*fracFull1)).astype('int64'), index=fraction1).reindex(range(TotalRows))
        data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(mean2, std2, round(selRows2*fracFull2)).astype('int64'), index=fraction2).reindex(range(TotalRows))
    data12 = data1.add(data2, fill_value=0)
    data[column] = data12
```

And the second, which takes double the inputs and combines it all in-function. These seem to work.